# Kill my app and all its (unknown) threads/tasks/services programmatically and automatically

Tags: android, task

I use a library that creates very CPU-expensive tasks in background, with continuous loops.

Although this library has some method to stop its work, that I call in the onDestroy() method of my app, there's probably some bug in it, because I noticed that there's still a heavy usage of the CPU when my app executes the onDestroy(), until I browse and kill it from the the task manager. Even calling finish() does not change: probably some async task keeps running.

Please note that I don't really know what service/task the library is running, so I don't have a way to address that task directly and stop it.

I would like to bypass the library and be sure that everything is **really** killed when my app is destroyed.

1. is it possible, or I get it wrong because onDestroy effectively does it, and I am just being fooled?
2. how can I detect any possible async task, background service, anything and clear it inside the onDestroy(), in the same manner as when a user kills the paused app from the task manager?